# Filters on Joins are not Propagated to the Relevant orm.relations

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Defining some basic structures here:

```
class A( Base ):

    __tablename__ = 'a'
    id            = Column( types.Integer(), primary_key = True )

    abs           = orm.relation( 'AB', lazy='joined' )

class AB( Base ):

    __tablename__ = 'ab'
    id            = Column( types.Integer(), primary_key = True )
    a_id          = Column( types.Integer(), ForeignKey( 'a.id' ) )
    b_id          = Column( types.Integer(), ForeignKey( 'b.id' ) )

    a             = orm.relation( 'A' )
    b             = orm.relation( 'B', lazy='joined' )

class B( Base ):

    __tablename__ = 'b'
    id            = Column( types.Integer(), primary_key = True )

    bas           = orm.relation( 'AB' )
```

Now say I have an `A` with multiple `B`s related to it (say `A.id = 1`) and I would like to filter based on these `B`s.  I do the following query:

```
a = db.session.query( A ).join( A.abs ).filter( AB.b_id = 1, A.id = 1 ).first()
```

At this point, I would expect `len( a.abs ) == 1`, but this is not the case.  In other words, the filters applied to the join are not propagated through to the orm.relation.  How do I get this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this issue is described in [The Zen of Eager Loading](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/loading.html#the-zen-of-eager-loading) which comes down to this: You will have two distinct joins in your query. One is for building the correct join to filter on (which is what you produced with `.join(A.abs)`) and the other is for loading the relation (which the ORM automatically inserts based on `lazy="joined"`, otherwise it would query it on acess).

Now there are several ways around this. But first you should think about what you really want. Because when you say `A.abs` you really say "**all** the AB entries that belong to this A". But when you specify a single `b_id` than that's not what you want, because that's not what this relationship stands for. So here is the clean way:

```
db.session.query(A, AB).join(A.abs).filter(AB.b_id = 1, A.id = 1)
```

Now you get the `AB` as the second returned object from the query. This is how to do it correctly, because having only one `AB` in `A.abs` would actually be lying to the ORM: That's not true here (and it could break stuff). However, if you would insist on doing that it is possible. You can disable the double joins with [sqlalchemy.orm.contains_eager](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/loading.html#sqlalchemy.orm.contains_eager):

```
db.session.query(A).join(A.abs).options(contains_eager(A.abs)).filter(AB.b_id = 1, A.id = 1)
```

This will yield an `A.abs` with only one entry which has `b_id = 1`. However, as already stated that is not a nice solution and not what you should do.

As an additional hint, I suggest you turn on `echo=True` or even `echo="debug"` in your engine to make sure you see the queries being executed. If you look at your original query, so will see two joins on the same table.

Comment: I will also need to add the join condition manually to the filter for the first solution, won't I?  For example `db.session.query( A, AB ).filter( AB.a_id = A.id, AB.b_id = 1, A.id = 1 )`

Comment: If you omit the `join` part, you must manually do this, else SQLAlchemy can do this for you.